# How to transfer bulk of files from S3 to Lambda?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-glue

We have a S3 bucket, contains a folder 'A' which gets a file everyday. A lambda does some processings on the file in A and pushes that file to other folder 'B' in the S3 bucket, also deletes that file from A. **This lambda runs everyday at a fixed time, triggered by CloudWatch.**

**Problem**: 'A' folder in the S3 bucket has some older (1 year of data) daily files which is still there, because Lambda had some issues, and hence it was unable to process those daily files for that particular duration. That issue is fixed now and we need to backfill for older data. How to read those files in 'A' folder in S3 and pass it to Lambda for further processing?

One *sample solution* could be: Write a logic (could be a new Lambda function/Glue job) for iterating over those files one by one and push each file to the original lambda for processing.

What could be the best approach for this problem, considering the potential **failure** scenarios during processing?

Comment: You could try copying the files on top of themselves, which _might_ trigger Lambda. This can be done with `aws s3 cp` but some data (eg metadata) needs to change to allow it to work. Or, copy the files to a new location within the path that will trigger the Lambda function. Worst case, download them and re-upload them. S3 Batch Operations can also be used to trigger Lambda with some existing objects, but the Lambda function needs to be coded differently. See the red box on: [Invoke AWS Lambda function](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/batch-ops-invoke-lambda.html)

Comment: Or invoke the Lambda with a mock event like `{"Records":[{"s3":{"bucket":{"name":"bucket-name"},"object":{"key":"object-key"}}}]}` for the existing keys.

Comment: @anon-coward, Could you please elaborate more? What kind of invocation it is : Sync or Async? What are the keys here and how to invoke the lambda with mock event like this? I am new to AWS world, any links or resources to follow.

Comment: The keys are the existing keys to objects you have in S3 already.  You can invoke events with boto3's [invoke](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/lambda.html#Lambda.Client.invoke) either synchronously or asynchronously, or use the test invocation in the Web Console if you have a small number of objects.

Comment: I decided to use a script to invoke the Lambda synchronously. Script will iterate over the dates (for which the files are stored in the S3) and invoke the Lambda. Lambda will fetch the file from S3 for every date in every invocation, processes it, deletes that day file from S3, return the response to invoker. Do you see any flaw with this approach?


Where can this script be deployed? (EC2, Step function,  etc. ). Since script will take more than 1 hour for complete iteration as calculated, this can't be deployed to another Lambda.